# Are there other numeric adjectives beyond vingt-et-unce?

Tags: adjectives

As numeric adjectives go, we are all familiar with once, twice, and thrice. A few years ago, I did some research, and found quarce, quince, sece, sepce okce nince dekce, elfce duss, and baikce; and, in addition, found vingtaince (20 times) and vingt-et-unce (21 times). Though I doubt that these words have any depth of history (but are merely clever neologisms) I have found several of them useful. Is anyone aware of any words for 14-19 occurrences? What about 100, 500, 1,000, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused about what you mean by "useful", since people get along perfectly fine using "four times, five times, six times" etc. As with "clever", perhaps that's a matter of opinion.

In any case, I found the following on a Wiktionary talk page:

> ### More number words
>
> The words for number of times (quarce, quince etc., continuing the
>   sequence once-twice-thrice) have been coined and re-coined so many
>   times that it's not clear any one version has more right to be on the
>   page than another. I've added all the versions I know of and
>   cross-referenced them so that people can decide for themselves which
>   to use.
>
> In case anyone needs a citation, here are the lists and their
>   respective provenances:
>
> - **First seen here**, and not to my knowledge anywhere else: *quarce,
>     quince, sess, sepce, okce, nince, dekce, elfce, duss, baikce* (**stops at
>     13**)
> - **Used by the DROD computer games**: *quarce, quince, sence, septence,
>     octence, novence, tonce, elevonce, twolce, thorce, **quartonce,
>     quintonce, sextonce, septonce, octonce, noventonce*** (**stops at 19**)
> - Correctly[*] formed from the Latin number-names: *quarce, quince, sece,
>     septence, octence, novence, decence, undecence, duodecence,
>     tredecence, **quattuordecence, quindecence, sedecence, septendecence,
>     decenoctence, decennovence,** vicence.* I also added the Latin-derived
>     words for every tenth number up to 100. 91.107.133.40 14:52, 26
>     November 2008 (UTC)

([Appendix talk:List of protologisms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix_talk:List_of_protologisms#More_number_words))

*editorial note: I have no idea what the Wiktionary editor means by using the word "correctly" in this context; it's a nonsensical description. The most that can be said for "septence" is that it looks more like a real English word than "sepce" does. That doesn't make it in any way "correct".

The [contributions page for that IP address](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Special:Contributions/91.107.133.40) shows edits adding the following entries, among others, to the Wiktionary list of "protologisms":

- > *tricence*: thirty times
- > *quadragence*: forty times
- > *quinquagence*: fifty times
- > *sexagence*: sixty times
- > *septuagence*: seventy times
- > *octogence*: eighty times
- > *nonagence*: ninety times
- > *centence*: one hundred times

Comment: *Correctly* here is a phrase meaning, they tried to mangle the Latin name for a number through the same process as for *unum* → one → *once*, *duo* → *tuuo* → two → *twice*, *etc*